# Why there is no .jar file in my OpenCV Folder?

Tags: java, opencv, homebrew

I recently downloaded OpenCV using Homebrew, and I'm facing an issue when trying to add the library to my editor. I can't find the .jar file as instructed in the tutorials I've followed online. I've gone through multiple tutorials, but unfortunately, I haven't made any progress.

I have already tried `brew edit opencv` and set `DBUILD_java` to `ON`, but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.